# bitset or native data types with bitwise operations for bitmap?

Tags: c++, primitive-types, bitset

I would like to implement bitmaps of 64 bits, 128 bits and 256 bits. I was thinking of using specialized classes for these three.  I need to set the bits and also look them up. The bitset will not be dynamic, static implementations of 64, 128 and 256 bits will be used.

What are the pros and cons of using the c++ bitset over using a native type like long long and manipulating the bits using bitwise operations?

Is there any overhead in using bitset in initialization or in any other factor?

Thanks

Comment: A decent implementation of `std::bitset` would be specialized for small numbers of bits, such that it would use appropriate sized integers when possible. Then there shouldn't be any difference between bitset and the native type. No telling if your implementation is decent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, definitely there is some overhead in standard bitsets. Your implementation is going to be faster (but you need to invest some effort in coding it and making it efficient and bug-free).

I would however use standard bitsets and not fight against that overhead until this is a proven bottleneck. You know the often cited saying about about premature optimization, right?

Comment: Am I the only person who read that paper? 90% of it was justifying the use of GOTO!

Comment: @MSN: not only you - and I find using GOTO justified in certain cases.